# what does the flag IRQF_SAMPLE_RANDOM specify while registering interrupt handlers?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In request_irq() to register interrupt handlers, why we use the flag IRQF_SAMPLE_RANDOM and what is entropy pool?

Answer (score 3):

The entropy pool collects randomness for the `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` devices.

In outdated kernels, you would have used `IRQF_SAMPLE_RANDOM` to tell the kernel that the times at which your device generates interrupts are unpredictable.

Since kernel version 3.6, the kernel handles interrupt randomness automatically, and this flag no longer exists.